# TCP Echo client C program

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm a newbie to socket programming and am trying to run execute the following code but without any luck!
OS       : Ubuntu 16.10
Compiler : GCC

echo service is running on port 7.

Here's the code: Takes IP address as 1st argument, port number as 2nd and string to be sent as the 3rd.

```
void exit_with_error(char *);

void exit_with_error(char *err_msg)
{
   printf("%s",err_msg);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  system("clear");
  int socket_num,port_num, recv_bytes;
  char *ip_addr;
  char *Txstring;
  char *RxString;
  struct sockaddr_in servAddr;

  ip_addr=argv[1];
  port_num=atoi(argv[2]);
  Txstring=argv[3];

 //Construct server address structure
 memset(&servAddr,0,sizeof(servAddr)); 
 servAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
 servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_network(ip_addr);
 servAddr.sin_port = htons(port_num) ;

 socket_num=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);

 if(socket_num==-1)
  exit_with_error("Socket creation failed...\n");

 //connect to echo server
 if(connect(socket_num , (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr,  sizeof(servAddr) ) < 0)
   exit_with_error("Connection failed !\n");


 //Send the string to server
 send(socket_num,  Txstring, strlen(Txstring), 0);

 //Receive the string
 recv(socket_num, RxString, strlen(Txstring), 0);

 printf("Received; %s", RxString);


 close(socket_num);
 return 0;
}
```

When i run the program as : `./prog 127.0.0.1 7 Hello`

The output is             : `Connection failed !`

I cannot figure out why!

Comment: Use `perror` to get the actual reason of failure.

Comment: @user58697 Thanks, i used `perror` instead, and i got `Connection timed out!` which i already figured out because it took so long, it is not so detailed!

Comment: As far as I remember port range 1 - 1024 is reserved and should not be used by regular (non-root) users. Try changing port to 7000 for example. Also do you actually have a listening application at this port (server)?

Comment: @VTT I ran the program with as root with port 7 since there is already an echo service running, and i got Network unreachable this time, if i have to give 7000 i need to start the corresponding service on my machine right? Also, isn't the program itself the listener, or should i use the `listen()` function in my program?

Comment: Yes, if you want to write a server you need to create a listening socket and wait for connections. Running fresh programs as root is not recommended.